# how to make the layout adapt to the screen size in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, layout, native

I wanted to know how I can do so that the objects of a layout can be adjusted to the different sizes of the screens of cell phones or tablets.

For example:

If I assemble the design for a small screen (Nexus S) it looks good on that screen, but if I emulate in a pixel 2 XL you see everything small.

How can I adapt the elements or what property are used to fit all screen sizes?

Comment: What units are using for sizing your elements?  Have you tried viewport units (vw, vh, vmin)?

Comment: I'm new to react native, I just put style = {{width: 360, height: 50}}

Comment: I apologize; you are correct in doing that as RN sizing is unitless.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer would be to add a function that adjusts the dimensions (or fontSize) depending on the screenSize. but from my personal experience I wouldn't recommend to use it as you could end up on huge Pictures or Texts for big phones and Tablets. I am currently using [react-native-extended-stylesheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet) which offers great support for `media-queries, variables, dynamic themes, relative units, percents, math operations, scaling and other styling stuff`

Your code will look something like that:

```
const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  column: {
    width: '80%'                                    // 80% of screen width
  },
  text: {
    color: '$textColor',                            // global variable $textColor
    fontSize: '1.5rem'                              // relative REM unit
  },
  '@media (min-width: 350) and (max-width: 500)': { // media queries
    text: {
      fontSize: '2rem',
    }
  }
});
```